# How do I open google maps app via my app in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios, url-scheme

In iOS 8 and earlier, I was able to launch the google maps app (if installed on the user's device) by using the URL SCHEME 'comgooglemaps'

However, with iOS 9, I know the URL Schemes need to be validated in the info.plist file. But where do I add this information?

I haven't found any documentation on google maps sdk for iOS.

Also, I am using the latest available google maps sdk i.e. 1.10.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add **`LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`** as an array into your `plist` and then add any scheme url you need into as a string.

Comment: I want to be able to use google maps to navigate to passed location, not only open google maps

Comment: @SafwanHijazi you can see the documentation for google maps SDK here.. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme?hl=en#display_directions

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive contribution Patel, next time you downvote, read the OPs Q and then complaint about accepted A that is perfectly fine for others.